# I need an appropriate Python data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, python-2.7

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have boxes `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` and have balls `a` ,`b` ,`c` ,`d` ,`e`, `f`, ... -- each of which is in one of the aforementioned boxes. So I know that, for example, balls `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are in box `A`. Balls `e`, `j`, `p`, and `w` are in box `B`, etc.

I'm trying to color each ball based on which box contains it, so I need a data structure to keep and handle this information efficiently.

My first thought was to keep a dict like `{'a':'A', 'b':'A',... 'w' : 'B' ...}` and if `a`'s value is `A` color him (for example) red, but I'm not sure that this is the best way to keep info in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Another way can be keeping a dictionary with the boxes as keys and the set of balls as values:

```
boxes = { 'A' : set('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 'B' : set('e', 'j', 'p'), ... }
```

Then you can iterate over the keys and color all the balls in the corresponding set with the same color.

```
for box in boxes:
    for ball in boxes[box]:
        color(ball, box)
```

Comment: The problem is:I am getting requirements from outside like find ball j and color it, then find ball b and color it, etc. I cant iterate through boxes and color the balls.

Answer (score 1):

What is efficient would depend on what you are doing and how often you are doing it. There isn't much information in your question to hazard a guess.

For example, it is not clear whether all balls in the same box have the same colour. If that is so, then you could assign the colour to the box rather than to the ball for maybe space efficiency; but what do you want to make efficient?

A lot of quesswork could be spared if you showed some of your code.

Comment: The balls and boxes are just an example. The real situation is that I have Gui tool with different windows and I have a configuration file in which parameters are set. I am parsing configuration file and trying to set the same params from the GUI (they're in different windows in my GUI). Now the problem is that I can't dynamically detect the window in which the parameter that I want to set, so I want to keep "param : window" information and use that during reading configuration file and set corresponding parameters in windows